# Why is a polyfill.js file being created even when my .browserlistrc only targets "last 1 chrome version"?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Here is an image of the build of a new Angular (v10) application.

[image]

Here is the `tsconfig.base.json`:

```
 {
    "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2020", "dom"]
      },
      "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
      }
    }
```

Here is the contents `.browserlistrc` file:

```
last 1 Chrome version
```

My question is: why is there a `polyfills.js` file? Wouldn't the fact that I'm targeting the latest ES version as well as the latest Chrome version negate the need for any polyfills? Or am I misunderstanding the use of that type of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the actual output of `polyfills.js` and experimenting with what happens when it's removed, I discovered that Angular "Zones" functionality is provided through that file.

For example, if I remove the `polyfills.js` script import statement, this error gets hit:

```
if (this.hasPendingMacrotasks = !1,
    this.hasPendingMicrotasks = !1,
    this.isStable = !0,
    this.onUnstable = new Hs(!1),
    this.onMicrotaskEmpty = new Hs(!1),
    this.onStable = new Hs(!1),
    this.onError = new Hs(!1),
    "undefined" == typeof Zone)
    throw new Error("In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js");
            https://angular.io/guide/zone#setting-up-zonejs
```

Digging further, I found that all of this is even in the [Angular documentation on Zones](https://angular.io/guide/zone#setting-up-zonejs) and is also the one uncommented-out line `polyfills.ts`:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

So, TLDR; as long as you are using Zones in your Angular application (and there are ways to remove it), you will always have a `polyfills.js` file as part of your build output.